# Unable to Connect to AWS RDS Postgres from local system

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have created an AWS RDS Instance with Postgres 10.6

I am trying to connect to it from my local system using below command:

```
psql --host=dev.xyz.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com --port=5432 --user="postgres" --password --dbname=abc
```

The Inbound rules i have set are

Allow TCP traffic on 5432 from Anywhere.

Still I am getting below error:

```
psql: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
Is the server running on host "dev.xyz.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com" (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

[image: List of Subnets]

Comment: Which subnet have you placed the database in, if it is not in a public subnet that will not work. You need to give us more information about your configuration before we can help you.

Comment: @lijat the subnet group is default one (default-vpc-xyz)

Comment: Is that a public subnet, can you show the configuration, same with the sequrity group.

Comment: @lijat I have an ec2 instance also running with django project, I am able to connect to this RDS instance from there

Comment: then it sounds even more like a network problem

Comment: Which IP/Host are you using to connect to this host ? Is it a public IP/DNS reachable over the internet ?

Comment: @ankit Are you trying to connect from your own computer on the Internet? If so, what is the setting for `Publicly accessible` on the RDS database? Was it set to `Yes` or `No`?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Its set to no

Comment: If you need to access postgres for debugging, it is not recommended to make it available to public. Please do not use this in production without proper security measures unless there are any other use cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Publicly accessible = No`, then you will not be able to access the RDS database from outside the VPC.

This is because the DNS Name of the database will not resolve to an IP address.

Comment: How can i change it to yes